# Calculation from two queries in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 2 queries that give me counts. I want to divide one count by the other - I currently have the below SQL but throws out errors immediately:

```
    SELECT tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team,
           Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs,
           Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total,
           [Q_manager_CHS_Total].[CHS_Total]/[q_managers_backlog_total].[backlogs] AS Expr1
FROM Q_Manager_CHS_Total
INNER JOIN
(
    Q_Manager_Backlog_Total
    INNER JOIN tbl_CEAR_Name
        ON Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.CEAR_Team = tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team
)
    ON Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CEAR_Team = tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team
ORDER BY Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs DESC;
```

Comment: And the error you get would be?

Comment: I don't see any counts, and I only see one table mentioned.  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your first join isn't syntactically correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You totally banjaxed your joins... Try this

```
SELECT tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team,
       Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs,
       Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CHS_Total,
       [Q_manager_CHS_Total].[CHS_Total]/[q_managers_backlog_total].[backlogs] AS Expr1
FROM Q_Manager_CHS_Total
INNER JOIN
(
    select Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs, tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team
    FROM Q_Manager_Backlog_Total
    INNER JOIN tbl_CEAR_Name
        ON Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.CEAR_Team = tbl_CEAR_Name.CEAR_Team
) T1
    ON Q_Manager_CHS_Total.CEAR_Team = T1.CEAR_Team
ORDER BY Q_Manager_Backlog_Total.Backlogs DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the count field [backlogs] in query [q_managers_backlog_total] has 0 as a result somewhere. If you then try to divide by 0 you will evidently get an error. Catch a 0 value in the underlying query and you're good.